# Azure AD App registration Graph API does not have permission to write to MS Teams

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to send a message to certain team and channel in Microsoft Teams through Graph API. I registered my application on Azure Active directory and added multiple permissions.

[image]

Additonally, I was trying to follow instructions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
I get an error in code :
[image]

How can I add Microsoft 365 Subscription to my created tenant. Microsoft's guidelines are not very helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/746484/unable-to-create-team-using-ms-graph-api) could be helpful to you. The API requires you to set `team-id/channel id/chat id` so it requires to have a team first. But for a tenant, it doesn't have a tenant by default. You might need to buy a license such as M365 license and assign it to your user account and use it to create teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "***Teams is disabled for the tenant. Ensure the tenant has a valid Office365 subscription***" usually occurs if the user is not assigned with O365 license.

To resolve the error, make sure to subscribe to Microsoft 365 subscription. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant).

Then ***Go to Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Licenses -> Assignments -> Select Office 365 -> Save***

[image]

Make sure **Microsoft Teams is enabled:**

[image]

After assigning the required licenses, **I am able to Send chatMessage in a channel successfully** via Microsoft Graph API like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/TeamsID/channelChannelID/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
"body": {
"content": "Hello World"
}
}
```

[image]

**To do the same in C#**, refer the below code snippet:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);
var requestBody = new ChatMessage
{
Body = new ItemBody
{
Content = "Hello World",
},
};
var result = await graphClient.Teams["{team-id}"].Channels["{channel-id}"].Messages.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

**Reference:**

[Unable to create Team using MS-Graph API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/746484/unable-to-create-team-using-ms-graph-api) by CarlZhao-MSFT